# Cross-referencing tables {SEQ Table \\* arabic} and figures {SEQ Figure \\* arabic} with officedown [i.e. block_caption() and run_autonum()]

Tags: r, r-markdown, officer, officedown, crosstable

I want to create a `.docx` report with [{officedown}](https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officedown-for-word.html#officedown-for-word), but instead of using "bookmark" reference types for cross-referencing my tables and figures as suggested in [ch.4.6](https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officedown-for-word.html#caption-label-for-figures-and-tables) and [ch.4.7](https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officedown-for-word.html#cross-references) of the User Documentation, I would like my references to be actual "Figure" and "Table" reference types in the resulting `.docx`. As discussed in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55737333/8830099), this would require `{SEQ Figure \\* arabic}` and `{SEQ Table \\* arabic}` word fields and the answers show how to implement this via `officer::slip_in_seqfield()` or `crosstable::body_add_table_legend()`.

However, I think, **these approaches to obtain actual "Figure" and "Table" reference types only work for the {officer} syntax and not the {officedown} syntax**. To be clear, so far I understood

- **{officer} syntax** as an R-script that makes use of a `dplyr` chain that starts with `read_docx() %>%` [[example](https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officer-for-word.html#titles)]
- **{officedown} syntax** as an Rmd-script that makes use of `block_caption()` and `run_autonum()` within a chunk [[example](https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officedown-for-word.html#cross-references)]

<sup>(please correct me if I am wrong)</sup>

Therefore, I would like to know whether there is a way to modify the suggested approach in {officedown} in order to obtain actual "Figure" and "Table" reference types that I can also cross-reference in the text. Below is an example using the standard suggested approach:

````
You can also make use of the `run_autonum()` and `block_caption()` functions 
of the {officer} package. Here are the cross references to Table \@ref(tab:tabmtcars2) 
and Figure \@ref(fig:figmtcars2). This approach can be used for tables and figures 
and the corresponding reference type in MS Word will always be "bookmark".

```{r}
# Table
run_autonum(seq_id = "tab",
            bkm = "tabmtcars2") %>%
  block_caption(autonum = .,
                label = "mtcars table",
                style = "Table Caption")

head(mtcars)

# Figure
ggplot(head(mtcars), aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
  geom_point() + theme_bw()

run_autonum(seq_id = "fig",
            bkm = "figmtcars2") %>%
  block_caption(autonum = .,
                label = "mtcars figure",
                style = "Image Caption")
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my first time posting here, so sorry if I get formatting/etc. incorrect.  But if I understand you correctly, officer::run_reference may be what you are looking for.  Thomas de Marchin gives a really helpful example of this [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/awesome-r-markdown-word-report-with-programmatically-inserted-headings-outputs-and-19ad0de29a22).

The essence of this is to use block_caption with officer::run_autonum in your r code block, and then use officer::run_reference in the markdown in the place of \@ref(tab:some-tab) as follows:

````
```{r}
block_caption(label = 'The Caption',
              style = 'Table Caption',
              autonum = officer::run_autonum(seq_id = 'tab', bkm = 'some-tab'))

head(mtcars) %>% flextable()
```
 This is a reference to Table `r officer::run_reference('some-tab')`
````

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in crosstable's vignette (https://danchaltiel.github.io/crosstable/articles/crosstable-report.html),
you can use this syntax:

````
---
title: "mtcars"
output: bookdown::word_document2
---
    
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(crosstable)
library(flextable)
library(ggplot2)
```

Table iris is given in Table \@ref(tab:tabmtcars2).

```{r tbl, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat("<caption> (\\#tab:tabmtcars2) Table Iris </caption> \n\r ")
head(mtcars) %>% flextable
```


A figure about mtcars is given in Figure \@ref(fig:tabmtcars).

```{r fig, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat("<caption> (\\#fig:tabmtcars) Figure of mtcars heard </caption> \n\r ")
ggplot(head(mtcars), aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
  geom_point() + theme_bw()
```
````

The numbering will be correct, but **it won't create any MS Word field**, so you will not be able to include these bookmarks in a figure summary, for instance.

I'm not aware of any way to include such fields using Rmarkdown, but you could use the officer syntax (described in the same link) in a plain R script.